WSO2 API call with Keycloak and Spring fails
I have an application written in Spring Boot using the Spring Security library for role and permission management, and I'm trying to integrate WSO2 API Manager with Keycloak as the Key Manager.
I have successfully implemented Keycloak as the Key Manager within WSO2, and I can generate the application's token subscribed to the product without any errors. (When I make the call to the API WITHOUT role-based protection, the call goes through successfully.)
However, when I try to call the API through WSO2, I need to send the token for the application validation but also need to validate the user's permissions who, through the front-end, calls the API.
I've searched for solutions on various sites, implemented different scenarios, and tried on my own, but I always end up hitting the same error.
The question is, how do I validate both the application and the user to correctly call the API protected by a role?
It would be helpful to receive support from experienced individuals to resolve this tricky issue.
Thanks everyone for the support.

Where are your users defined? Are users created in the API Manager?

The users are saved in Keycloak, I need to validate user realm roles

One thing you can try is to onboard the users to the WSO2 APIM, and create and assign required roles to the User in the APIM. Then create scopes with role mapping and assign those scopes to respective API resources. Generate the token with required scopes. Invoke the API with the generated access token. If the user has the roles assigned, he/she will get the token with the requested scopes otherwise with a default scope. With this, you can confirm whether the specific user has access to the API and can access it without an issue. (Note that this solution is without Keycloak as KM)
